# Poisson Distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics

In an urbanization, there are an average of 13 cars damaged in a month. I computed the probability distribution for possible number of damaged cars in the range from 0 to 30.

X <- seq(0,30)
dpois(X,13)

But I don't know how calculate the probability to have the number of damaged cars great than or equal to 14.

*Is about the syntax of >=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a certainty (i.e. a probability of 1) that somewhere between 0 and infinity cars will be damaged in a month, so the probability that 14 or more will be damaged is 1 - the sum of probability that 0 to 13 cars will be damaged.

Therefore you can do:

```r
1 - sum(dpois(0:13, 13))
#> [1] 0.4269554
```

Or, as MrFlick points out,

```r
1 - ppois(13, 13)
```

Comment: Or just `1 - ppois(13, 13)`

Comment: @MrFlick thanks. I'm afraid I was trying to be "fastest gun in the West" on this one and was working on a more detailed explanation when you commented. But you're right of course. Updated with acknowledgement.

Comment: or `ppois(13,13,lower.tail=FALSE)` (which is both more verbose and less interpretable, but will be much more accurate for extreme values)

Comment: @BenBolker I didn't realize that - thank you.

Comment: try `ppois(100,13,lower.tail=FALSE)` (if you want *really* extreme values you need to use `log.p` to compute the value on the log scale: `ppois(1000,13,lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)`)